# How to disable stripping tags for View header?

Tags: views, forms, 8

I have created an view and set its header to:

```
<div class="filters">
    <strong>Filters</strong>
    <select><option value="Select filter" disabled default">Select filter</option></select>
</div>
```

But when I access it (via block created from view and placed anywhere on website) I get:

```
<div class="filters">
    <strong>Filters</strong>
    Select filter
</div>
```

So how to prevent Drupal 8 from stripping those form tags?

Comment: Have you tried using a theme template for your view (such as as views-view-mycustomviewname.html.twig) and adding your custom markup there instead of through the view UI?

Comment: I know it's an option but it's more like work-around then solution for me. And it's less flexible - end-user no longer can do it via CMS (admin panel). But anyway, thank you for this suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Please got to the view you have created and follow the below steps :

1. Header > Add > Type "Text area" in Search
2. Select Text area > Add and configure header
3. Under the content insert

> ```
> <div class="filters">
>     <strong>Filters</strong>
>     <select><option value="Select filter" disabled default">Select filter</option></select>
> </div>
> ```

4. Dont forget to change the Text format  to Full HTML and click on save